# How to make every object in list null

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list and I have populated it with myObjects. I do  processing with the the objects and then I would like to have the objects garbage collected by releasing references to the objects. How would this be best acheived?

I can't use foreach loop because you can't alter the collection within the loop.

Comment: What do you want to achive? Clear the list?

Comment: What do you mean by _"make [an] object […] null"_?

Comment: Remove all references to an object. If you have 1000 objects rererenced in a list - is it possible to remove these references

Comment: @user theList.Clear()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This updates the list, and doesn't create a new list with new contents.

```
for (i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
    list[i] = null;
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks - was thinking foreach which can't be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to iterate through the list, and assign each object to null, like so:

```
var myList = new List<object>();

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    myList.Add(new object());
}

for (var i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    myList[i] = null;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the `List(T).Clear()` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a.aspx

This dereferences all objects and sets Count to 0.

If you really need to keep the same count and set each item in your list to null, you can simply use `ForEach()`:

```
list.ForEach(x => x = null)
```

Comment: That removes objects completely

Comment: That's right, I clarified the answer.

Comment: This doesn't update the list.

Comment: Your `ForEach` example is just setting the local `x` reference to null, not updating the items in the list itself.